# What is the best approach to clean up old lambda versions?

Tags: aws-lambda

I have lambda versions enabled in my CFN template. Over the time, I see that versions are incrementing, and now it consumes code storage space allocated by AWS.

I would like to know what is the best approach to remove old versions. i.e. I just want to keep current version and one before that, remaining all should be deleted.

**Option-1:**

- Create a script and run it periodically.

  - I am seeing many examples of this. People are referring/following this approach.
  - https://github.com/NiteDesign/Lambda-Version-Cleanup/blob/master/Infra-Lambda-Cleanup.js
  - https://github.com/epsagon/clear-lambda-storage

**Option-2** (not sure if this is possible or not)

- CFN solution

  - i.e. I use `AutoPublishAlias` attribute to enable lambda versions like below. Is there a way to limit versions in the template itself?

```
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    AutoPublishAlias: $LATEST
    Handler: yourHandler.handler
    FunctionName: !Sub "YOUR-FUNCTION-NAME"
    CodeUri: dist
    Events:
      healthGet:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /YOUR-FUNCTION-NAME
          Method: GET
```

Answer (score -1):

I would create a new lambda function run on schedule (event bridge) and then inside that lambda function we can use any aws sdk for example Python boto3 to get all lambdas check for unused version and remove it